# How do you find the position at which three particles obey $m_1 a_1 = m_2 a_2$ if two of the particles form a composite body?

Tags: classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

From Classical Mechanics by Kibble:

> Consider a system of three particles, each of mass m, whose motion is
> described by (1.9). If particles 2 and 3, even though not rigidly bound
> together, are regarded as forming a composite body of mass 2m located
> at the mid-point $r=\frac{1}{2}(r_2 +r_3)$, find the equations describing the motion
> of the two-body system comprising particle 1 and the composite body (2+3). What is the force on the composite body due to particle 1? Show that the equations agree with (1.7). *When the masses are unequal, what is the correct definition of the position of the composite (2 + 3) that will make (1.7) still hold?*

(1.9) is $$ m_1 a_1 = F_{12} + F_{13}, \\ m_2 a_2 = F_{21} + F_{23}, \\ m_3 a_3 = F_{32} + F_{31}.$$

(1.7) is $$ m_1 a_1 = -m_2 a_2 $$

---

So I've done the first part, however I don't know how to do the bit in italics. Apparently the answer is $$ r = \frac{m_2 r_2 + m_3 r_3}{m_2 + m_3}, $$
but I don't understand where this answer is coming from.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a step back and note that this result should be intuitive. The formula given is the weighted average of $r_2,r_3$ with each position contributing proportionally according to its mass. I.e. the total mass is $m_{23}=m_2+m_3,$ and then the position $r_2$ makes up $\frac{m_2}{m_{23}}$ of $r$ and $r_3$ makes up $\frac{m_3}{m_{23}}$ of $r$. The resulting $r$ (from now on I will call it $r_{23}$) is called the center of mass of objects 2 and 3.

You can find this algebraically by positing that the combined mass of the objects should be $m_{23}=m_2+m_3$ and then trying to find the acceleration that multiplies it in the net force. Add (1.9.ii) and (1.9.iii) and you get $$m_2a_2+m_3a_3=-m_1a_1.$$ We want to write the LHS as $m_{23}a_{23}$, so just forcibly factor out $m_2+m_3$ from the existing expression and call what's left $a_{23}.$

$$m_2a_2+m_3a_3=\underbrace{(m_2+m_3)}_{m_{23}}\underbrace{\left(\frac{m_2a_2+m_3a_3}{m_2+m_3}\right)}_{a_{23}}.$$

Integrate $a_{23}$ and you have $r_{23}$ as given.

Comment: Okay, that make sense. While I do have a good familiarity with calculus, I wasn't expecting it to be needed here. However, I now understand what's going on so thanks for you answer.